# LINQ value.Contains function error

Tags: linq, ravendb

i am facing an error while using contains function of LINQ query

following error occured

```
Contains is not supported, doing a substring match over a text field is a very 
slow operation, and is not allowed using the Linq API.
The recommended method is to use full text search (mark the field as Analyzed and
use the Search() method to query it.
```

here is my query

```
query = from u in Session.Query<Article>() where u.Tags.Contains(tags) orderby u.CreationDate descending select
```

`StartWith/EndsWith` works fine but it is not full filling my requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, Contains won't work and you need to use Analyzed fields. You can start here: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/configuring-index-options

Comment: would you please provide me a chunk of code or hint as im unable to understand the code provided on RavenDB's site

Comment: Create an index (via code or the Studio), and set the field as Analyzed. The article I linked to shows how to do this from code; via the studio it is done by clicking on "Add Field" in the index definition, typing the field name and selecting "Analyzed". Then you can replace the Where() operator in your query with Search(), and it will just work.